# Integrating SOAP in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to integrate soap client in my laravel project to call soap based web services. I have tried laravel-soap but due to lack of resources I am having trouble in getting it started.
Other option is I am trying to get started with php soapclient in my laravel project.
I want some kind of demo working so that I can understand how it is integrated in my laravel project.
Can you guys please provide me some resources?
Help much appreciated.

Comment: I have tried to use soap based webservice from soap-laravel/artisan but not working.

Comment: The instructions specified here seem pretty straight forward. https://github.com/artisaninweb/laravel-soap

Comment: Is this laravel-soap good for large projects?  Also I am having trouble when integrating with following message: object(App\Soap\Response\GetConversionAmountResponse)#211 (1) { ["GetConversionAmountResult":protected]=> string(1) "0" } object(App\Soap\Response\GetConversionAmountResponse)#213 (1) { ["GetConversionAmountResult":protected]=> string(30) "737.08262696248249428760964100" }

Comment: any good resources for for integrating soap based web service with laravel web client to display items.

Answer (score 1):

Try this package http://github.com/ACFBentveld/Soap its very easy to use.